# GeoJSON in Leaflet generated by gdal2tiles

Tags: leaflet, geojson, gdal2tiles

I have generated a leaflet map with gdal2tiles out of my rasters and it works wonderful. Now I want to add my shapes in form of GeoJSONs and I have my difficulties.

To the gdal2tiles generated script, first I assign a variable to my geojson and show the location of it.

```
// GeoJSON
var Pad = L.geoJSON('./Padarchol/Padarchol.geoJSON');
```

Than I gather all my geoJSONs under one var, like it is done with the basemaps and the overlaymaps.

```
var shapes = {"Padarchol": Pad,}
```

In the end I add all of those layers

```
L.control.layers(basemaps, overlaymaps, shapes {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

Result is a blank page. Without  these addings leaflet presents me a wonderful map...

Comment: Does anythig show in the browser error console? In Firefox, press F12 to open it.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  leaflet.html:100:55. and this is the line         L.control.layers(basemaps, overlaymaps, shapes {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

Comment: okay I added a comma after "shapes". Now it says: "L.geoJSON is not a function"

Comment: `L.geoJSON` with Leaflet 1.x, `L.geoJson` with Leaflet 0.x (pay attention to the case)